# Configuring Apache with Django

Tags: django, apache, django-admin, mod-wsgi, apache-config

I'm trying to configure Apache with Django. Everything is working except the admin panel. It's static files are not loading. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-the-admin-files) talks about different ways of doing it but none are working for me.

Here is my 0000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin maahd@meddy.co
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

Alias /static /var/www/html/sp-django-master/meddy1/static        

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
include sites-available/meddy.co.conf
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Here is my meddy.co.conf where meddy.co is my website:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName ec2-54-254-141-40.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
        ServerAlias www.ec2-54-254-141-40.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/sp-django-master/meddy.wsgi

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sp-django-master

    #Alias /static /var/www/html/sp-django-master/meddy1/static

    <Location "/static/">
            Options -Indexes
        </Location>

    #AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /var/www/html/sp-django-master/meddy1/static/meddy1/css/$1

    AliasMatch ^/([^/meddy1]*\.css) /var/www/html/sp-django-master/meddy1/static/meddy1/css/$1
    AliasMatch ^/([^/admin]*\.css) /var/www/html/sp-django-master/static/admin/css/$1   

    Alias /static/ /var/www/html/sp-django-master/meddy1/static/

    <Directory /var/www/html/sp-django-master/meddy1/static>
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/sp-django-master/mysite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /media/ /var/www/html/sp-django-master/uploads/

        <Directory /var/www/html/sp-django-master/uploads>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

    Alias /static/admin/ /var/www/html/sp-django-master/static/admin/

</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you run "manage.py collectstatic" first? What is the error message?

Comment: Yes I ran it without errors.

Comment: I mean, what is the error when you try to access any of your static assets using Apache? Is it a 404, a 403, or something else?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://ec2-54-254-141-40.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/static/admin/css/base.cs